# Showing a Fragment as BottomSheet in Android

Tags: java, android

In android latest versions, a new feature of Bottom sheets has been introduced which allows showing popups as bottom sheets. For example,

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
        View sheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.any, null);
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

And you can show the popup as bottom sheet view.

My problem is that I have to do a lot of code for my apps functionality say 100-200 lines of code but keeping this code inside same activity or fragment makes my code ugly and unmanageable. Is there a way that I can extract out this code to some Fragment or other activity such that all the code related to bottom sheet dialog remains inside it's own class.

I am not looking up for any java hacks. Rather android way of doing this is expected.

How to open and close the bottomsheet view?

Comment: How about using a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`?

Comment: Why do people do a -1 for no reason? Is the question not clear enough or is the problem statement not valid?

Comment: Lack of research? I must say that it's got to be near impossible to search for `BottomSheetDialog` and `Fragment` without coming across `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

Comment: okay! I can delete the question but that way believe me SO shouldn't have questions other than a code issue as you would always be able to find something on google or in documentation. I can show you 10000 instances of such questions which are basic but people have shared good information on those.

Comment: Anyways I was able to find good link to medium when i put  bottomsheetdialogfragment https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider to use [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment) instead

Comment: @Vinay if you found this answer correct please approve it :)

Comment: that's not a answer bro. A link could answer probably but could go into comments. Can you share the code for how to make a bottomsheet fragment work and close how it's lifecycle works?

Comment: link refers to official android document so it is impossible to be invalid in near future :)

Comment: It don't have a working example though. I will be exploring more before I accept this answer but yes +1.

Answer (score 1):

As Zafer Celaloglu said can do so

```
kotlin
class MyDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "FilterDialogFragment"

        fun newInstance() = FilterDialogFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_my_layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}

java
public class MyDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_my_layout, container, false)
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

and call in activity like that

```
kotlin
MyDialogFragment.newInstance().show(supportFragmentManager,MyDialogFragment.TAG)

java
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
myDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");
```